# Can I get help converting a Oracle procedure over to SQL with certain commands

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I cannot seem to convert this procedure over for the life of me, and really need it converted to SQL procedure. I am having an issue in the 'for rec' and other loops that are a part of the select queries. The following is the conversion, but as you can see, two areas aer still  the oracle procedure, and I cannot figure out how to convert it.

```
 create procedure get_right_string(
@p_bitstring       varchar(4000) out,
@p_app_id varchar(4000)          /* mccapps.application.application_id%type */,
@p_sec_user varchar(4000)        /* mccapps.app_user.sec_user%type */ )
as

begin
set nocount on;

set @p_bitstring = '';

-- Loop through all rights for the user/app combo and mark as yes/no (1/0)
-- building a string bitmap, ex: '11010011'
declare rec cursor in (select distinct
              a.right_id,
              case  WHEN  b.right_id is null THEN  '0' ELSE  '1' END bit
            from app_right a,
              ( select
                  rol.app_role_id,
                  rol.app_parent_id,
                  rol.right_id
                from
                  app_role rol
                where
                  rol.application_id = @p_app_id
                --cannot figure out how to convert here down to prior    
                start with rol.app_role_id in ( select
                                                 b.app_role_id
                                               from
                                                 app_user a,
                                                 app_user_right_xref b
                                               where
                                                 a.user_id = b.user_id and
                                                 a.sec_user = @p_sec_user)
                connect by prior rol.app_role_id = rol.app_parent_id ) b
               --end of problem area
            where
              a.application_id = @p_app_id and
              a.right_id = b.right_id (+)
            order by a.right_id desc)
while 1=1 begin
  set @p_bitstring = isnull(@p_bitstring, '') + isnull(rec.bit, '');
end;
```

fetch rec into;
  end
  close rec;
  deallocate rec; get_right_string;

The code section I cannot seem to figure out how to convert is labled accordingly in the prior example. I have been at this for a day now, and help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really cannot convert `start with` directly in SQL Server.  One method is to create a recursive CTE for the code in Oracle and then move that over (recent versions of both databases support recursive CTEs).  Otherwise, you will need to figure out what the code does and rewrite it using SQL Server constructs.

Comment: how can you do a foreach type itteration on records return in a select within a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes you can, it will just be uglier than Oracle's syntax (my personal opinion).  Have a look [here](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-cursor-tutorial/).  And there are plenty more examples on the web.

Comment: SQL is the standard that most RDBMS implement. SQL Server is Microsoft's RDBMS.

Comment: @Casey . . . You should avoid cursors if you can do something similar using set-based operations.  Cursors -- also known as RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row -- can seriously impede performance.